# Train huggingface's GPT2 from scratch : assert n_state % config.n_head == 0 error

Tags: python, nlp, huggingface-transformers, transformer-model, gpt-2

I am trying to use a GPT2 architecture for musical applications and consequently need to train it from scratch. After a bit of googling I found that the issue #1714 from huggingface's github already had "solved" the question. When I try the to run the propose solution :

```
from transformers import GPT2Config, GPT2Model

NUMLAYER = 4
NUMHEAD = 4
SIZEREDUCTION = 10 #the factor by which we reduce the size of the velocity argument.
VELSIZE = int(np.floor(127/SIZEREDUCTION)) + 1 
SEQLEN=40 #size of data sequences.
EMBEDSIZE = 5 

config = GPT2Config(vocab_size = VELSIZE, n_positions = SEQLEN, n_embd = EMBEDSIZE, n_layer = NUMLAYER, n_ctx = SEQLEN, n_head = NUMHEAD)  
model = GPT2Model(config)
```

I get the following error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-7-b043a7a2425f>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('C:/Users/cnelias/Desktop/PHD/Swing project/code/script/GPT2.py', wdir='C:/Users/cnelias/Desktop/PHD/Swing project/code/script')

  File "C:\Users\cnelias\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 786, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\Users\cnelias\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 110, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "C:/Users/cnelias/Desktop/PHD/Swing project/code/script/GPT2.py", line 191, in <module>
    model = GPT2Model(config)

  File "C:\Users\cnelias\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\transformers\modeling_gpt2.py", line 355, in __init__
    self.h = nn.ModuleList([Block(config.n_ctx, config, scale=True) for _ in range(config.n_layer)])

  File "C:\Users\cnelias\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\transformers\modeling_gpt2.py", line 355, in <listcomp>
    self.h = nn.ModuleList([Block(config.n_ctx, config, scale=True) for _ in range(config.n_layer)])

  File "C:\Users\cnelias\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\transformers\modeling_gpt2.py", line 223, in __init__
    self.attn = Attention(nx, n_ctx, config, scale)

  File "C:\Users\cnelias\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\transformers\modeling_gpt2.py", line 109, in __init__
    assert n_state % config.n_head == 0
```

What does it mean and how can I solve it ?

Also more generally, is there a documentation on how to do a forward call with the GPT2 ? Can I define my own `train()` function or do I have to use the model's build-in function ? Am I forced to use a `Dataset` to do the training or can I feed it individual tensors ? 
I looked for it but couldn't find answer to these on the doc, but maybe I missed something.

PS : I already read the blogpost fron huggingface.co, but it omits too much informations and details to be usefull for my application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the error message is pretty clear:

> `assert n_state % config.n_head == 0`

Tracing it back through [the code](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/v2.5.1/src/transformers/modeling_gpt2.py#L99), we can see

> `n_state = nx  # in Attention: n_state=768`

which indicates that `n_state` represents the embedding dimension (which is generally 768 by default in BERT-like models). When we then look at the [GPT-2 documentation](https://huggingface.co/transformers/model_doc/gpt2.html#gpt2config), it seems the parameter specifying this is `n_embd`, which you are setting to `5`. As the error indicates, the embedding dimension **has to be evenly divisible through the number of attention heads**, which were specified as `4`. So, choosing a different embedding dimension as a multiple of `4` should solve the problem. Of course, you can also change the number of heads to begin with, but it seems that odd embedding dimensions are not supported.

Comment: thanks a lot !!
I am bit a of a github noob, would you mind telling me how you found the piece of code from which the error was comming from ? I tried to do that myself and after a while of doing ```ctrl + f``` on every file of the repo I gave up.

Comment: No worries, good to see you working on problems by yourself. For this specifically, I worked my way backwards through the error message. Right above the `assert ...` in the error message you can see the path to the file where this specific line happened to be. From there on it was quite easy to find it, although I can otherwise recommend you to use the github search bar (which by default starts searching *in the current repository* and thus works as a quite neat alternative). Note that this is a one-off response, since the formal thing would be to open a new question on this (unrelated) topic.

Comment: I had the same problem and error message. Making `n_embd` a multiple of the number of attention heads indeed solved it.